# How to set default logger or loggerRef when using log eip in Camel

Tags: logging, apache-camel

I'm using the Camel *log* EIP from Java:

```
from("direct:source")
    .log("Hello");
```

I understand that I can specify the logger in each log() call.  But, how can I set a default logger once for all the routes in a CamelContext or route builder class.  This way I can use package scoping to enable detailed logging for just specific log() calls without having to mention the logger in every call.

If that is not straightforward, another option is to change the default package name from *routeId* to *camelContext*.*routeId*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup a logger in the Camel Registry, then the log EIP will use it, but there has to be only one, see the source code:

https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/model/LogDefinition.java#L94

Comment: This worked.  For reference, I added the following to the main \@Configuration class:

    \@Bean
    public Logger logger() {
builders
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainSpringBootRouter.class);
    return logger;
    }

Unfortunately, this approach loses some of the goodness of the default logger in terms of type converters.  So, I am inclined to keep the default and organize routeId's using prefixes to allow scoping debug levels.